# Node.JS :How to forward to the login page with parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am building the login function with node.js, express,express-session, ejs.

This is the log-in page (i.e. index.ejs)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Video Chat Room</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
        <style>
            #message
            {
                color:red;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var messageBox=document.getElementById("message");
<%
                if  (typeof errorField!="undefined") {
                    switch (errorField) {
                        case "email":%>
                            messageBox.innerHTML="Your email address has been used by another user, please use another one.";
                            document.getElementById("email").focus();
<%                          break;
                        case "logoutSuccess":%>
                            messageBox.innerHTML="<%=alias%> has successfully logged out.";
<%                          break;
                    }
                }
%>              
            });
        </script>   
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            Nick name/Alias:<input type=text required name="alias" value="<%=((typeof user=='undefined')?'':user.alias)%>"><br>
            Email Address:<input type=email id="email" required name="email" value="<%=((typeof user=='undefined')?'':user.email)%>"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <div id="message">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the server-side code(i.e. server.js)

```
........
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
   res.render('../ejs/index.ejs');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

var alias = req.body.alias;
var email = req.body.email;
var user=require("./classes/user.js");
user.alias=alias;
user.email=email;

if (user.login) {
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect('/home/');
} else {
   res.locals.errorField="email";
   res.locals.user=user;
   res.render('../ejs/index.ejs');
}
```

It works fine, however, when the login process failed, although the web output the login page(i.e. index.ejs), the browser address bar still stay in "/login"; is it possible to change the browser address bar to "/" and the index.ejs can read the errorField and user value also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a user login error to go back to `/`, then you need to do `res.redirect("/")`.  If you want to add some parameters to that page that can be used either in server-side rendering or client-side rendering, then the simplest way to do that is to add query parameters:

```
res.redirect("/?error=email")
```

Then, either your server-side rendering or some client-side Javascript can pick up that query parameter and display something like a message in the page that explains what happened.

There are lots of ways to do something like this. Here's a partial list:

1. Send data in a query parameter that server-side rendering picks up and adds some explanatory text to the page.
2. Send data in a query parameter that client-side Javascript picks up and adds some explanatory text to the page.
3. Set a cookie that contains an error message that your server-side rendering will pick upon the redirect and then clear the cookie.
4. Set some error data in the user session object on the server that your server-side rendering will pick up when rendering the redirected page and the clean that info from the session.
5. Use an Express middleware module built for these temporary messages called [flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash).
6. Render an error page from the server (without an immediate redirect) and then have a client-driven redirect back to "/" that occurs after a few seconds time. The client-driven redirect can either be from a `<meta>` tag or can be client-side Javascript on a timer.